# How to enable a disabled button in code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have disabled a button in javascript. On page load I need to enable it again.

This is my code in script.

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnsubmit.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
});
```

In code behind,I am enabling it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     btnsubmit.Enabled = true;
}
```

but its not enabled.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server side event  `Page_Load` always run first..So you are enabling the button first and then disabling it in the clientside `$(document).ready`..

I don't know what is your goal.But you can solve the problem by..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     btnsubmit.Enabled = false;
}
```

Javascript..

```
$(document).ready(

    function () {
        document.getElementById("<%=btnsubmit.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
    });
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677626/which-one-is-run-first-between-page-loadobject-sender-eventargs-e-and-docum) for extra reading...

Comment: Did the answer satisfies your need?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `btnsubmit.disabled = false;`

like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page load runs when the page is rendered on the server - First.
After the page gets rendered on the server it gets to the client and then the js starts running.
Your page load assignment gets overridden on the clients end.

You can do both on the server(enable\disable).

delete this:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnsubmit.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
});
```

And use this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     if(blah blah blah)
        btnsubmit.Enabled = true;
     else
        btnsubmit.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out , using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonID/.buttonClass').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

and through javascript use

```
document.getElementById("buttonid").setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp button in front end. And choose enable false to disabled it.

```
<asp:Button id="btnName"  runat="server" Text="Add"  Enabled="false"/>
```

Then you can enable it in server side.

```
 btnName.Enabled = true;
```